# Are "hot dogs" (the food) really "perritos calientes" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, comida

In Cristina Henriquez' novel "El Libro de Los Americanos Desconocidos", the American food item known as "hot dogs" is translated as "perritos calientes" (literally "hot dogs" or "dogs hot").

Is this correct? After all, "hot dogs" makes no sense, as they are not made from dog meat any more than hamburgers are made from pig meat.

In German, "hot dogs" are called "Würstchen" (little sausage), which makes more sense. Have Spanish speakers really just transliterated our nonsensical word for "wieners"/"frankfurters" to "perritos calientes", or is this a faulty translation, perhaps because the Spanish-speaking world doesn't indulge in such gourmet items?

BTW, speaking of German/American food, my guess is that "Hamburgers" are called that because they originated in Hamburg, and "Frankfurters" are called that because they originated in *that* German city (not Kentucky).

Comment: At Charles DeGaulle Airport in Paris when I was last there the menu at one of the restaurants offered *Saucisses Americaines* (sp?), presumably because the Acadamie frowned on people saying "hot dog." BTW. you can find the etymologies of [frankfurter](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=frankfurter&allowed_in_frame=0) and [hamburger](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hamburger&searchmode=none) at etymonline.com.

Comment: In tv dubbings is always translated as "perros calientes" or "salchichas", but in real life (at least in mexico) they're just "hot dogs" and sometimes "jochos" (a shortened form of hot dog).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

Es cierto que en muchas partes se les llama "perritos calientes".
No sabía del origen del nombre, pero en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrito_caliente) leo:

> El origen del término hot dog se debe, supuestamente, al humorista
>   gráfico Tad Dorgan (1877-1929), que escribía y hacía tiras de dibujos
>   en el New York Evening Journal. Dorgan asistía a un partido de béisbol
>   en el estadio de Polo Grounds en 1901 de los New York Giants. Él oyó
>   como Harry Stevens vendía las salchichas diciendo: "*They're red hot!
>   Get your dachshund sausages while they're red hot!*" («Están al rojo
>   vivo, adquiera sus *dachshund* (perro salchicha) mientras están al rojo
>   vivo»). Finalmente esta analogía inspiró a Tad Dorgan a representarlo
>   así en sus tiras cómicas: un "*dachshund*" en un pan", lo que dio la
>   idea de *hot dog* (perro caliente). Sin embargo, algunos investigadores
>   discrepan de esta historia y exponen diferentes argumentos acerca de
>   su veracidad.

De la misma fuente, nombres: Perro caliente, jocho, maño, panchito (Bolivia), pancho(Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay).

Pero nunca he oído en España otra cosa que "perrito caliente" o "salchicha".

---

**ENGLISH**

It is true that in many places they are called "*perritos calientes*".
I did not know the origin of the name, but in [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrito_caliente) I read:

> The origin of the term hot dog comes from, supposedly, the cartoonist
>   Tad Dorgan (1877-1929), who wrote and made drawings strips in the New
>   York Evening Journal. Dorgan attended a baseball game at the Polo
>   Grounds stadium in 1901 from the New York Giants. He heard Harry
>   Stevens sold sausages saying, "They're red hot Get your *dachshund*
>   sausages while they're red hot!" Finally this analogy inspired Tad
>   Dorgan to represent this way in their comic strips. A "dachshund" on a
>   roll, which gave the idea of hot dog. However, some researchers
>   disagree with this history and expose different arguments about its
>   veracity.

From the same source, names: *Perro caliente*, *jocho*, *maño*, *panchito* (Bolivia), *pancho* (Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay).

But I never heard in Spain anything but "*perrito caliente*" or just "*salchicha*".

---

[image: A Tad Dorgan's comic strip]

Comment: Es muy común en España en los bares al referirse y al escribir usar la palabra Frankfurt, aunque según el diccionario panhispánico de dudas se debe escribir Fráncfort, en este caso, la salchicha de Fráncfort. DPD:" El topónimo tradicional sigue vigente en el uso, por lo que se desaconseja el empleo, en su lugar, de la forma alemana Frankfurt."